# How do you get the seed fieldname from a table programmatically?

Tags: mysql, count, seed

Is there anyway to get the seed fieldname?
What I mean by seed is the field that's been created with something like this; 
INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

I plan on using this ( getting the seed field name pro grammatically ) in coming up with the fastest SQL query to get the number of records in a table.

The function I plan on writing is something like this. Please fill in the blanks and provide the getSeed function inner mechanics.

```
function get_record_count ($dbh,$table,$where){

//get the seedfield name in the {table} programmatically

$seed = getSeed($dbh,$table);
$sql = "select count({$seed}) as `count` from {$table} " . $where; 

//do the mysql query & get num rows to return it... 


}
```

Comment: you mean column name , right ?

Comment: Why are you specifically using COUNT against that column? Does it allow NULLs and you don't want to count them? http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: @Moyed Yes. It's the column name that I'm after.

Comment: @Marcus  Why would seed have a NULL in it? Counting the seed = counting the number of recs. Ain't it?

Comment: No. COUNT() doesn't count NULL values. If your seed column allows NULLs, counting seed won't be the same as counting the number of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not trying to count the number of non-NULL values in the column (`COUNT(expr)` doesn't count NULLs), then just use `SELECT COUNT(*)` and let MySQL use the same index that is used in the WHERE clause to answer `COUNT(*)`.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM {$table} " . $where;
```

Comment: count(seed) from table .... what's wrong with it? why are we talking about nulls? how could mysql allow a seed value to ever have a null in it to begin eith. see my point?

Comment: @AverageJoe, in your question, what does `{$seed}` expand to? Is it simply a column name?

Comment: seed is a field that's been created by something like this in the create table time.  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: @AverageJoe, then don't use `COUNT(column)`, use `COUNT(*)`, not only for the best performance, but also for the easiest code. [`COUNT(*)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) means count the number of rows, regardless of whether they have NULL values, but lets MySQL decide on the best column (index) to use to determine this. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/